# How to handle preflight request?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, cors, fetch, preflight

Im trying to send a post request to different origin server that support cors policy.

the problem is `content-type:application/json` .CORS pre-flight request (the OPTIONS call) can not be this Content-Type.
I also have another options to send with my header:
`Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type,deviceid,devicepassword,deviceversion`

[my network header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYvWr.png)

Is there any way to fetch data? 
 
 I am using react.js and backend services written by asp.net core

Answer (score 2):

Hope this fixes the problem.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy(Global.CORS_ALLOW_ALL_POLICY_NAME,
            builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowCredentials();
            }));

    services.AddMvc();
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseCors(Global.CORS_ALLOW_ALL_POLICY_NAME);

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: thanks but I did it before. I know the problem related to preflight .

Answer (score 1):

If pass the custom header, you need to add the specified request header.

```
     services.AddCors(option=>
        {
            option.AddPolicy("policyname", builder => 
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
        });
```

Remove the `credentials: 'include'`.

Another method: do not remove `credentials: 'include'`. Add  `AllowCredentials` in the bakend.

```
    services.AddCors(option=>
        {
            option.AddPolicy("policyname", builder => 
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials();
        });
```

Comment: yes thanks for your point, I add it. `.WithExposedHeaders("Accept","Content-Type","DeviceVersion","DeviceID","DevicePassword") `  but still fetch does not work! @Karney

Comment: @E.Shahri, how do you get it in the client, can you share some client code?

Comment: `fetch("Url", {
            mode: 'cors',
            credentials: 'include',
            method: 'POST', 
            body: JSON.stringify(
                {
                    phoneNumber: Number,
                }
            ),
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "DeviceVersion": "",
                "DeviceID": "",
                "DevicePassword": "",
            },
        })\` @Karney

Comment: @E.Shahri, do you want to send these headers to the bakend?

Comment: yes. I should send these headers to the backend  @Karney

Comment: @E.Shahri, try to remove `credentials: 'include'`.

Comment: still not working with removing it @Karney

Comment: @E.Shahri, because of post method, you need to add `AllowAnyMethod`, refer to the edited answer.

Comment: Yes I Have it...  I dont need WithExposedHeaders() any more?? @Karney

Comment: @E.Shahri, do you send it successfully?

Comment: @E.Shahri, the function of `WithExposedHeaders` is to response the headers to the client. Here you don't need it.

Comment: @E.Shahri, have you make it successfully?

Comment: unfortunately not working. with proxy on client side I can get it but when I upload it on my domain it failed because of different Port @Karney

Comment: @E.Shahri, do you use `AllowAnyOrigin`? What is the domain?

Comment: The CORS service returns an invalid CORS response when an app is configured with both methods. So, try to use the WithOrigins method to add the allowed Origins, code as below:services.AddCors((cors) => {cors.AddPolicy("AllowClientOrigin", policy => policy.WithOrigins("mydomain").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials());}); @Karney

Comment: I solved the problem  by moving the codes  to beginning of  ConfigureServices. thanks for your help... @Karney